# Thunderbird "Login to server imap-mail.outlook.com failed" error

Tags: microsoft-outlook, thunderbird

After using Thunderbird for a long time without issues, 1 of my accounts (only 1, not the others) suddenly started giving me the "Login to server imap-mail.outlook.com failed" error, promting a retry, entering a new password, or cancel, whenever it would check for new emails. I've checked online for solutions, but none I found worked. I've tried:

- Changing my password
- Ensuring the user name was the actual email address
- Ensuring 2-way verification is turned off (it was, so I set it up and turned it off again)
- Removing the account from Thunderbird and adding it again, manually ensuring all settings are correct (it won't let me add the account, claiming the username or password is invalid)

As noted before, my other (also Outlook) accounts function normally, and I can log in on this account everywhere else (including in the browser, with the Outlook app on my smartphone, and with the default Windows 10 Mail application). Does anybody know how I can get this account working with Thunderbird again?

**EDIT:** I have changed absolutely nothing about Thunderbird or my e-mail settings, nor did anything change about this situation after the 45.5.0 patch om November 18, but when I tried to add the account again today (for no other reason than to try it again) it let me add it normally. It also no longer gives me the error. As a result, I have no idea how to solve this problem or what solved it for me, but for those who share the issue: try it every once in a while. It may miraculously help.